# Eclipse for Mac doesn't recognize device for debugging after update to Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, device

All packages are updated and the SDK for my device's Android version are installed.

It says in the package manager that the Google USB driver is "incompatible with Mac O..." (it's cut off with no hover hint). But from what I've found on the web, it has said so before and has not been the reason. Should that be the problem, I'll happily try to install a compatible one.

USB debugging is of course enabled, and the whole kaboodle worked before the OS update.

When I plug it in (Xperia Z running 4.2.2), the OS itself recognizes the device. Same for another device, ZTE running 2.3.5. It also does not appear in Eclipse, even though I've used ti for debugging before on this Mac.

I've forced Eclipse to let me select device when running, but no devices appear there or in the devices tab as before.

I've tried to type adb devices in the elusive "command line" that is nowhere to be found. I've followed the various guides to somehow make the Terminal window visible in the window list, but the guides are outdated.

Android console says "adb is running normally".

I've restarted Eclipse, plugged and unplugged the device, enabled and disabled USB Debugging on the device. Nothing helps.

Has someone solved this?

Comment: Curious: Do emulators show up in adb?

Comment: Emulators did show up but also had problems, they couldn't launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my Mac and the USB driver "just worked" again. Sorry, just a bit unexpected since I have to restart my Mac rarely.

Then for a while, I got no messages in the LogCat, even in All Messages (no filters). And 10 minutes and a few launches later, it suddenly had 5000 messages mid-session.

Anyway, this sounds like a bug description so vote to close if you like.